# On the use of semi-colons in long lists

Tags: grammar, semicolons

I've always had a hard time with semi-colons and, this time, not even my English teacher was sure of what is its correct use in the following situation:

> It's about creativity, proving properties of mathematical systems and the naturally captivating, beautifully-crafted problems; it is about the arduous moments of head-melting logical thinking; the infinite possible pathways; the dead ends; the methodical yet creative logical arguments; the crawling focus that obscures all except thought; the moments before progress; and the illuminating, surging epiphanies.

Comment: The only people who *are* sure about the use of semi-colons are wrong.  There is no universally (nor even very-widely) accepted list of rules about when to use them and when to avoid them.  The use of semi-colons in your sentence seems to be OK to me.

Comment: If you mean it's about creativity and arduous moments, then no semicolons: *It's about creativity — proving properties of mathematical systems and the naturally captivating, beautifully-crafted problems. It's about the arduous moments of head-melting logical thinking — the infinite possible pathways, the dead ends, the methodical yet creative logical arguments, the crawling focus that obscures all except thought, the moments before progress, and the illuminating, surging epiphanies.*

Comment: This is awfully close to a proofreading request. We don't do proofreading. Please ask a specific question, preferably in the context of how a particular piece of advice or style guide should be interpreted.

Comment: Yes, this is an extension of the use of the semicolon as a 'super-comma' to disambiguate complex lists. << The sandwiches available are bacon, lettuce, and tomato; tuna and sweetcorn; and carrot, raisin, and pickled onion. >> (The last is a very recent creation.) If only we had a big comma and a little comma! Though the use in lists is reasonably widely accepted nowadays, the 'supercomma' used in running text, especially after a regulation semicolon, is doubtless frowned upon by many. But really good writers redefine the norms.

Comment: The heroic sentence reads like a stream of consciousness; thus no holds barred; all in; whatevvuh; do your thing and who is the reader to say you broke a rule; jumping between creativity to hard logic to creativity.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Over sixty years ago I was specifically taught the use of the semi-colon as a "super comma"  (although it wasn't called that) when listing items which, in themselves, contained commas. This still seems highly logical to me since, without the semi-colons how would the reader be able to work out the boundaries of the items? I wonder if any members of the "anti super-comma" faction have a workable alternative to it short of using bulleted lists which are not always appropriate

Comment: Please add a linked attribution. People's answers tend to shift along the 'unacceptable'-'acceptable' continuum if the author has sold millions and/or invented balrogs.

Comment: There is NO one “correct use”.  There are styles of English punctuation that have changed over the centuries. What should you do then? First, realize that punctuation is an aid to reading by indicating when to pause and for how long (relatively speaking). Second, the hierarchy of length in punctuation marks is , ; : .  And you can use an em dash (—) as an alternative to a comma for clarity. Learn how to save your own life, not what some stranger would do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read this sentence as containing two main clauses: "it's about creativity, proving . . . problems" and "it is about the arduous moments . . . surging epiphanies." These clauses are separated by a semicolon, which is perfectly fine. The second clause contains a list that is also separated by semicolons, but I see no reason to use semicolons in that list. (Semicolons are usually used in lists only when commas would cause confusion.) I'd simply replace them with commas:

> It's about creativity, proving properties of mathematical systems and the naturally captivating, beautifully-crafted problems; it is about the arduous moments of head-melting logical thinking, the infinite possible pathways, the dead ends, the methodical yet creative logical arguments, the crawling focus that obscures all except thought, the moments before progress, and the illuminating, surging epiphanies.

Of course, this is a very long sentence, and you could make it even simpler by breaking it up into separate sentences.

By the way, I see two more issues: 1) Most of the definite articles seem awkward to me, because as far as I can tell, most of the items are not specific. Some of this is a matter of style, but I'd probably delete most of the definite articles. 2) The list in the first clause (assuming that it is a list of three items) omits the Oxford comma, while the list in the second sentence retains it. That is inconsistent.

Comment: There has to be a trade-off between 'being simpler' and conveying the desired spacing, cadences. If forced to edit the author's rather novel semicolon usage (numbers 2 - 7) here, which to my mind is stylistically refined, I'd use a full stop after _problems_ and then ellipses (rules for which are indisputably woolly) in place of the avant-garde/naughty semicolons.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yes, ellipses are often used to indicate speech that is trailing off, so they could work well, too.